# Printed note vs Note which has been printed (What's the difference?)

Tags: meaning, difference, syntax

Footnote:

> A printed note at the foot of a page in a book.

Can I rewrite it this way?

> A note which has been printed at the foot of a page in a book.

Do both the sentence mean the same, even after changing the structure?

Comment: It's hard to see why anyone would want to explicitly include the word ***printed*** in such contexts (how else would the text come to be there?). So I'm sure the *most* common form would simply be your first version, but without the superfluous word ***printed***.  Next most common would be *A note **printed at the foot of a page** in a book.* There's a subtle difference of "emphasis" whereby *your* first version simply assigns the "meaninglessly superfluous" adjectival label ***printed*** to the note, whereas *my* second version references *the act of placing the note in a specific position*.

Comment: Yes. They mean essentially the same thing but the circumstances in which each might be used are quite different - essentially in the second example to distinguish that type of note from some other kind e.g. one hand-written on the back of a bus ticket. The first example can simply be referred to as "a footnote (on page 57)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'note' can refer to a small, informal, handwritten message. Like something you might write on a Post-it and stick somewhere. In fact, some people use such notes in books, especially students who might be making notes in a textbook. It's also common for students to write notes in the margins of textbooks. It's understandable why a dictionary might define a footnote as "a printed note" to avoid any possible confusion that it might be something added by the reader rather than the publisher.

Your re-writing of this definition makes sense grammatically, but it isn't as succinct, and arguably creates ambiguity. Saying it "has been printed" in a book could sound like it has been printed onto the book later.